# Collecting data with MPI_GATHERV

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am trying to parallelise a Fortran code with MPI_SCATTERV and collect data with MPI_GATHERV. I got the following error message, regarding MPI_GATHERV. I am not sure what is wrong.

This is the error message.

```
Loading compiler version 2022.0.2
Loading tbb version 2021.5.1
Loading compiler-rt version 2022.0.2
Loading oclfpga version 2022.0.2
  Load "debugger" to debug DPC++ applications with the gdb-oneapi debugger.
  Load "dpl" for additional DPC++ APIs: https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneDPL
Loading mkl version 2022.0.2
Loading mpi version 2021.5.1
Abort(69296142) on node 0 (rank 0 in comm 0): Fatal error in PMPI_Gatherv: Message truncated, error stack:
PMPI_Gatherv(397)..........................: MPI_Gatherv failed(sbuf=0x2b6dd01cb240, scount=881724165, MPI_DOUBLE, rbuf=0x2b6f901cc280, rcnts=0x2b6c0fc87fe0, displs=0x2b6c0fc87fc0, datatype=MPI_DOUBLE, root=0, comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIDI_Gatherv_intra_composition_alpha(2631): 
MPIDI_NM_mpi_gatherv(396)..................: 
MPIR_Gatherv_allcomm_linear_ssend(65)......: 
MPIR_Localcopy(46).........................: Message truncated; -1536141272 bytes received but buffer size is 8056
Loading compiler version 2022.0.2
Loading tbb version 2021.5.1
Loading compiler-rt version 2022.0.2
Loading oclfpga version 2022.0.2
  Load "debugger" to debug DPC++ applications with the gdb-oneapi debugger.
  Load "dpl" for additional DPC++ APIs: https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneDPL
Loading mkl version 2022.0.2
Loading mpi version 2021.5.1
Abort(136405006) on node 0 (rank 0 in comm 0): Fatal error in PMPI_Gatherv: Message truncated, error stack:
PMPI_Gatherv(397)..........................: MPI_Gatherv failed(sbuf=0x2b77a71a9d00, scount=210, MPI_DOUBLE, rbuf=0x2b77a71a9600, rcnts=0x2b77a7197fe0, displs=0x2b77a7197fc0, datatype=MPI_DOUBLE, root=0, comm=MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIDI_Gatherv_intra_composition_alpha(2631): 
MPIDI_NM_mpi_gatherv(396)..................: 
MPIR_Gatherv_allcomm_linear_ssend(65)......: 
MPIR_Localcopy(46).........................: Message truncated; 1680 bytes received but buffer size is 56
```

This is my code with MPI_GATHERV.

```
MODULE MOU
CONTAINS
SUBROUTINE PRO (br,n1,n2,n3)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER               ::      dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)
REAL (KIND=dp)                   ::      br(:,:,:,:)
INTEGER                          ::      i, j, k, l
INTEGER                          ::      n1, n2, n3
DO i = 1, n1, 1
   DO j = 1, n2, 1
      DO k = 1, n3, 1
         br(:,i,j,k) = (i*0.85+3.1)/(5.7-j)*(k**3-3.6)*DSQRT(br(:,i,j,k))
      END DO
   END DO
END DO
RETURN
END SUBROUTINE PRO
END MODULE MOU
PROGRAM EXAMPLE
USE MPI
USE MOU
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER, PARAMETER               ::      dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(15,14)
INTEGER                          ::      i, j, k, l
INTEGER                          ::      nu(4)
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE             ::      ns(:), rd(:)
INTEGER                          ::      nr, er, rn, ts, rs
REAL (KIND=dp), ALLOCATABLE      ::      ar(:,:,:,:), br(:,:,:,:), cr(:,:,:,:)
INTEGER                          ::      world_size, world_rank, ierr
INTEGER                          ::      nt
INTEGER (KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND)  ::      ra(2)
CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,world_size,ierr)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,world_rank,ierr)
nu(1) = 5
nu(2) = 6
nu(3) = 3
nu(4) = 2
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   ALLOCATE (ar(nu(1),nu(2),nu(3),nu(4)))
   DO i = 1, nu(1), 1
      DO j = 1, nu(2), 1
         DO k = 1, nu(3), 1
            DO l = 1, nu(4), 1
               ar(i,j,k,l) = (i+1)*(j/0.5-6.3)*DSQRT(DBLE(k)+3.9)/(l**2+8.3)
            END DO
         END DO
      END DO
   END DO
END IF
CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
ALLOCATE (ns(0:world_size-1))
ALLOCATE (rd(0:world_size-1))
nr = nu(2)/world_size
er = MOD(nu(2),world_size)
j = 0
DO i = 0, world_size-1, 1
   IF (i > er) THEN
      ns(i) = nr
   ELSE
      ns(i) = nr + 1
   END IF
   rd(i) = j
   j = j+ns(i)
END DO
rn = ns(world_rank)
ALLOCATE (br(rn,nu(1),nu(3),nu(4)))
CALL MPI_TYPE_VECTOR(rn,1,nu(2),MPI_DOUBLE,nt,ierr)
CALL MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(nt,ierr)
ra(1) = 0
CALL MPI_TYPE_SIZE(MPI_DOUBLE,ts,ierr)
ra(2) = 1*ts
CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_RESIZED(nt,ra(1),ra(2),rs,ierr)
CALL MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(rs,ierr)
br = 0.0d0
CALL MPI_SCATTERV(ar,ns,rd,rs,br,rn*nu(4)*nu(3)*nu(1),MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
CALL PRO(br,nu(1),nu(3),nu(4))
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   ALLOCATE (cr(nu(1),nu(2),nu(3),nu(4)))
END IF
CALL MPI_GATHERV(br,rn*nu(4)*nu(3)*nu(1),MPI_DOUBLE,cr,ns,rd,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
IF (world_rank == 0) THEN
   OPEN(UNIT=3, FILE='data.dat', STATUS='REPLACE')
   DO i = nu(1), 1
      DO j = 1, nu(2), 1
         DO k = 1, nu(3), 1
            WRITE (UNIT=3, FMT=*) cr(i,j,k,:)
         END DO
      END DO
   END DO
   DEALLOCATE (ar)
   DEALLOCATE (cr)
   CLOSE (UNIT=3)
END IF
DEALLOCATE (ns)
DEALLOCATE (rd)
DEALLOCATE (br)
STOP
END PROGRAM EXAMPLE
```

Would anyone please have a look at my example code and tell me what is wrong with my code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please do remember to use the [tag:fortran] tag. Please read the descriptions of the tags you are adding. Version tags should not be used alone and Fortran 90 in particular is a very old version long superseded by at least Fortran 95. Much fewer people will see your question if you use the wrong tags.

Comment: Broadcast and Scatter are two different operations that serve a very different purpose. If you design your programs around the way the data is distributed in parallel, you normally do not have to choose on or the other because only one makes sense. They simply do something different.

Comment: If you have large data structures, like a computational grid or mesh or an array of events or particles, where each parallel process should only on a part of it, then you give to that process only that relevant part of the data. A scatter operation is a way how to do it, but a very suboptimal one, because one process then has to have all the data before it scatters it. It is best if each process can prepare or read its own data independently. Scatters and broadcasts are good for transfering verious internal pieces of information that are not too big.

Comment: you could use scatter in order to allocate less memory on the non root ranks, but the way you are doing it is wrong. i recommend you start writing two trivial programs, one with bcast and the other with scatter that distribute data and print their `br()` to get familiar with how scatter works.

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet Thank you for the suggestion. I modified my example 2 code with MPI_SCATTERV and MPI_GATHERV. Would you please have a look at it and give me some more suggestions?

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you for the suggestion. I will be careful with the tags next time. I also modify my example 2 code. Would you please give me some comment? Thank you again.

Comment: @Vladimir I modified my code with MPI_SCATTERV and MPI_GATHERV. It seems that MPI_SCATTERV part was written correctly but MPI_GATHERV part was not correct. Would you please give me some more suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: The GatherV ans ScatterV variants are tricky so debugging them needs more time. However, I would still suggest to reconsider wheter you want this at all. In this way you still need the master rank to have all the data from all the nodes. For large arrays that is principially very problematic and not scalable. I also not that since FORTRAN 77 one should use `sqrt` and not `dqsrt` and the `stop` before `end` also is unnecessary and creates some extra messages.

Comment: I do not know what your application is, but take en example from fluid dynamics or from molecular dynamics. There you have arrays  for the fluid cells or lists of particles and that take a lot of memory. Each rank has its own part of the data. You cannot do any Gather operation of all the data to one rank, because there is not enough memory for that. One cluster node simply may not have enough memory to have all the data. All processes should be self-sufficient and they should all be reading and writing their necessary data from and to disk.

Comment: That said, Gather(V) is often used for varios auxiliary data so it still makes great sense to fix your problem. The error message suggests that you sent moch more data to a process than what it expected. As a first thing, check that the sum of the receive counts is equal to the sum of the send counts, provided the datatype is the same everywhere. If datatypes differ, check the total sizes. I normally always have several auxiliary MPI calls before the GatherV or ScatterV that synchronises the displacements and counts.

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you for the suggestions. I will think about how to ask each processor to write data to the disk separately. Maybe this could be the solution.

Comment: They can also all write to a single file together in parallel. Using libraries such as NetCDF or HDF5 or manually using MPI-IO.